# .destroy() generating error 'window.myChart.destroy()' is not a function

Tags: javascript, chart.js, destroy

I'm developing a profit and loss tracker for a game, i query an API that gives me item data, this data is then displayed using chart.js

My issue is that before the chart is updated, it should .destroy() the previous chart, however i get an error saying `window.myChart.destroy is not a function`

Below is the code used for this functionality;

// checks if myChart isn't null

```
    if (window.myChart != null){
    window.myChart.destroy();
  }
```

// creation of the chart

```
let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
       window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, { ... etc
```

// Updated attempt

```
if (window.myChart != null){
    window.myChart.destroy();
    window.myChart = null;
  }
```

Comment: Set 'window.myChart = null' just after destroy to ensure isn't it call twice.

Comment: @Mr. The current issue is that .destroy() isn't being recognised as a function

Comment: I had the same problem because I was trying to destroy it twice. And that's for destroy() does not set "window.myChart = null" but destroys the object entirely. In this case "if (window.myChart != null)" pass but the chart destroyed already.

Comment: I've updated the question to include my attempt, it's still giving the same error sadly, did it do it correctly?

Comment: According to docs "This must be called before the canvas is reused for a new chart."
Can you use update() instead destroy and rebuild it?

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html

Comment: Maybe, preferably I need to get .destroy() working, super confused as to why it's not currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declared a function after the chart has been created;

```
function destroyChart() {
  myChart.destroy();
}
```

As this is called after the chart is declared, it works correctly

so in your case, call `destroyChart();` before the chart function.

```
  destroyChart();
  displayGraphs();
```